# Not able to push to a protected branch (gh-pages) using actions in github

Tags: git, github, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I am having issues while trying to update gh-pages branch using github workflow. The `gh-pages` branch is protected , so I need to use personal access token for this. The fine-grained token has workflow, repo accesses and I have the admin rights for the repo.  But i get this error when the workflow is triggered.

```
  /usr/bin/git push origin gh-pages
  remote: Permission to dlt-science/science-notes.git denied to singhparshant.
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dlt-science/science-notes.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
  Error: Action failed with "The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"
```

Below is my workflow yml file:

```
name: deploy-book

# Only run this when the master branch changes
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    # If your git repository has the Jupyter Book within some-subfolder next to
    # unrelated files, you can make this run only if a file within that specific
    # folder has been modified.
    #
    # paths:
    # - blogs/**

# This job installs dependencies, builds the book, and pushes it to `gh-pages`
jobs:
  deploy-book:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      packages: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # with:
      #   persist-credentials: false
      #   fetch-depth: 0

    # Install dependencies
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    # Build the book
    - name: Build the book
      run: |
        jupyter-book build blogs/

    # Push the book's HTML to gh-pages
    - name: GitHub Pages action
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3.6.1
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
        publish_dir: ./blogs/_build/html
```

Comment: why do you protect that branch when you generate it anyway? its not what you asked for, but perhaps gives you some inspiration. Apart from that, which part of the error message puzzles you specifically?

Comment: I am protecting the github pages branches, so that not every collaborator can run the `gh-pages` command and update the hosted website. Only the workflow/admin should be able to do it. Regarding the error message, I have generated the token as an admin. But still get permission denied. 
I gave these permissions to the token- "Repository access"-> All repositories. "Repository permissions"-> R/W for actions, contents, deployments, secrets, workflows. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: I understand that with the protected branch. Do what you need to do. For trouble-shooting setup (temporary!) another branch that is not protected and see if you can get it to run. Then protect the branch, and adopt. Then finalize the setup for the protected gh-pages branch. This is merely a permission issue, but you have to keep in mind that there are multiple permissions in effect when dealing with gh-pages publishing (deployment) and then also for your protected branch setup and then also for the actions in that repository and then also for the repository.  Take care.

Comment: Still facing this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a token can override the branch protection. You may want to create a bot user, and give that user allowance to override the branch protection. Then create the personal access token for that bot user. IIRC this is also suggested somewhere in the Microsoft Github Documentation, they specifically mention to create a new user account to have a bot.